# How to transpose Cells in Excel by keeping certain cells constant?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, vba

I would like to know to transpose data in Excel with keeping certain cells unaltered. Attached images will give detailed idea. Image 1- Raw data. Image 2- Way i need to get the output.(every 5th cell needs to unaltered).[Raw data & Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGD4s.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592)?

Comment: You have incorrectly stated your requirement. You do not want to transpose a long list while keeping some cells fixed. You want to transpose A1:A5 to D1 then A6:A10 to D2 then A11:A15 to D3 and so on. This is a simple transpose with a loop round it. One difficulty is that A16 only has 3 following rows implying it is not a fixed number of rows per transpose. My suggestion: (1) Use the macro recorder to get the syntax for a transpose. (2) Tidy up the macro recorder's code and put a loop round it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 2 FOR loops, one for rows (i) and one for columns (j).  This also counts your rows (rCount) of data and will run the loop through the end of the range.  Lastly you need a pointer to keep track of where you are in the raw data (rPoint).

Assumptions:

- 5 rows per data set
- Data should be placed in ColD-H.

Code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim rCount As Integer
Dim rPoint As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    rCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row / 5
End With

For i = 1 To rCount
    For j = 1 To 5
        rPoint = j + (i - 1) * 5
        Cells(i, j + 3) = Cells(rPoint, 1).Value
    Next j
Next i
```